# Passing floats from fortran to .Net

Tags: c#, dll, floating-point, fortran

We are migrating an application from VB6 to .net c#.

The application uses a fortran dll to perform some calculations. The fortran is called from our code (VB6 and c#) and we notice that there seems to be some differences in a floating point variable fetched in c# than vb6.

So for example if we have the following fortran code:

```
subroutine FloatTest (delta) 
      !ms$attributes DLLEXPORT, ALIAS: 'FloatTest ' :: FloatTest 
      !ms$attributes REFERENCE :: delta
real*4  delta
delta = 1.0/3.0
END
```

Any idea why do we get a floating point value of 0.333333343 in c# instead of the 0.3333333 we get in VB6?

Thanks.
Niro

Comment: I'm passing floats from fortran to VB6 and to C#. However, the results are different between VB6 and c#. In VB6 we get 0.3333333 and in c# we get 0.333333343. I'm not sure why the c# value seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is accurate.  The fortran code is using 4 byte floating point (aka float or single), a format that can store only has 6.5 significant digits.  Printing more just produces random noise digits.  Use real*8 to improve the accuracy to 15 significant digits.  Or modify the print statement to show no more than 6 digits.

Comment: Be aware that the `real*4` and `real*8` notation, although widely supported as an extension, is non-standard. For portable code, use the intrinsic function `selected_real_kind` to request the precision you need.

Answer (score 2):

You're using limited precision arithmetic.  Binary numbers can only approximate `1/3`.

It appears that C# is configured to print more decimal places, since both results agree in the first 7 digits.

The value printed by C# "seems wrong" to you, but it is in fact more accurate than the value printed by VB.